# Registering a lot of UICollectionViewCell classes for reuse in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, wwdc

I'm following a [Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/) WWDC Session, where Apple engineers shown an approach to compose multiple `UICollectionViewDataSource` objects together to achieve better code reusability and separation of concerns.

In my app I use an `UICollectionView` and would like to implement a similar approach to building a UI.

An `UICollectionView` requires registering classes for reuse before actually using them.

Are there any potential pitfalls if I register all the possible `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses used in the app, when only a handful is actually needed for the particular screen?

By designing the app this way I'll avoid the need to introduce a custom protocol and querying the `DataSource` for what cell subclasses are actually used in the `UICollectionView`.

Another approach, is to register the cell every time before dequeuing it:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let model =... GET MODEL 
    let cellClass = MODEL.cellClass
    // Registering the cell class every time before dequeuing, ensuring it will be registered before dequeued
    collectionView.registerCellClass(cellClass)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellClass.reuseIdentifier(),
                                                  for: indexPath)
    cell.configure(model)

    return cell
  }
```

What are the drawbacks of this approach, if any?

Comment: This code `collectionView.registerCellClass(cellClass)` should be outside of `cellForItemAt` method . You can keep in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @PaulMarshal Thank you for your comment. I know it. The question is about the case, when the controller doesn't knows which cell classes to be displayed. So, there are 3 options: ask the DataSource beforehand, register all of them in `viewDidLoad` or register every cell before dequeueing it. What I'm asking is whether there are any drawbacks in cases 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering before dequeueing is likely very inefficient, so I would not recommend that out of the options you have.

Although I don't have true diagnostics to show it, registering every possible cell class in `viewDidLoad` should not greatly impact performance, since this is what Apple recommends.

You can make separate methods to register particular cell classes depending on the class of the data source. However, in the grand scheme of things, this is not something that you should want to focus on if you want to improve performance or speed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before I moved to registering every possible cell, I used your last method. I.e., asked the `dataSource` for `usedCellClasses` and registered them. Also, that's what Apple shown in their "Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views" 2014 WWDC talk.

On your 2nd part of the answer - could you please give a link to the Apple material where they recommend doing that?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW5): "Use either the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method to associate your cell with a reuse identifier. You might call these methods as part of the parent view controller’s initialization process." `viewDidLoad` is equivalent to the initialization process when using storyboard since your collection isn't wired up until then.

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing related to the performance impact.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy I could not find anything regarding the performance, but since Apple recommends registering at that point, I'd presume that there is no significant impact.